# Sequelizejs returns id besides the object for associated table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
class User extends Sequelize.Model {
    static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        return super.init(
            {
                id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11), allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true},
                cityId: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
                    field: 'city_id',
                    references: {
                        model: City,
                        key: 'city_id'
                    },
                    allowNull: false, defaultValue: 0
                }
            },
            {
                tableName: "users",
                timestamps: false,
                sequelize
            }
        );
    }

    static getByIdWithCity(id) {
        return this.findOne({
            where: {
                id: {
                    [Op.eq]: id
                }
            },
            include: [{model: City}],
            raw: false
        });
    }
}

class City extends Sequelize.Model {
    static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        return super.init(
            {
                cityId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, field: 'city_id'},
                countryId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED, allowNull: false, default: 0, field: 'country_id'}
            },
            {
                tableName: "city",
                timestamps: false,
                sequelize
            }
        );
    }
}

User.belongsTo(City, {foreignKey: 'cityId', targetKey: 'cityId'});
City.hasOne(User, {foreignKey: 'cityId', sourceKey: 'cityId'});
```

`getByIdWithCity` returns:

```
{
    "id": 15,
    "cityId": 3538,
    "City": {
        "cityId": 3538,
        "countryId": 4
    }
}
```

Why does it return `cityId`?

Of-course I can exclude this fields:

```
static getByIdWithCity(id) {
    return this.findOne({
        where: {
            id: {
                [Op.eq]: id
            }
        },
        attributes: { exclude: ['cityId'] },
        include: [{
            model: City,
        }],
        raw: false
    });
}
```

But is it the right way?

Answer (score -1):

It returns `cityId` because it's defined in your model.

Yes `exclude` will do it neatly, another way to achieve the same result is by explicitly writing which attributes you want using the `attributes` option (which is basically an `include`)  :

```
static getByIdWithCity(id) {
    return this.findOne({
        where: {
            id: {
                [Op.eq]: id
            }
        },
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [{
            model: City,
        }],
        raw: false
    });
}
```

so yeah same as :

```
attributes: {
  include: ['id']
}
```

As to how do it the "right way", i think it depends :

`exclude` can come in handy when you want to return more than just a single attribute from the query, for example imagine that a `User` model has 13 total attributes and you want them all except 2 of them, in that case it makes more sense to just use `exclude` rather than explicitly writing all the 11 attributes using the `attributes` option.

and vise-versa :
explicitly writing what attributes you want using the `attributes` option can come in handy if you want to return only 2 out of the 13 attributes, in this case it makes more sense to explicitly write them rather than excluding the rest 11 attributes.

In your case right here, you only have one attribute `id` and you only want to exclude one attribute `cityId` it doesn't matter wether you use `include` or `exclude` because they will run the same query : `SELECT id ..`, and you can just remove the `cityId` from the model definition (if you don't need it) but keep it in the migration.